# ContentResolver delete ContentUri deletes ambiguous file, why is it behaving this way?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver

I don't understand why this delete is behaving this way. I am adding a ringtone to a contact with a Uri built with

```
    val fContUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.absolutePath)
          val values = ContentValues()
          values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.absolutePath)
          values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ExFilename.ext")
          values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3")
          values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true)
    
    val contactUri = resolver.insert(fContUri!!, values)
```

Now if I run the insert multiple times, the entry shows up multiple times in the contact which I expect. However, when trying to delete the entry, if I use

```
resolver.delete(fContUri!!,null, null)
```

where

```
println("Running delete content uri ~ " + fContUri)
outputs 
content://media/external_primary/audio/media
```

Only the entry I just inserted is deleted, if it's inserted multiple times all of them are deleted. However I'm wondering why it doesn't delete everything else in the path, there are multiple other entries when I run

```
   val projection = arrayOf(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE)
                val cursor: Cursor? = call_activity.contentResolver.
                query(fContUri!!, projection2, null, null, null)

                val gdn = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                val gs =   cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
                if (cursor != null) {
                    try {
                        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            if (gdn >= 0 &&
                                gs >= 0
                            ) {
                                val displayName =
                                    cursor2.getString(gdn)
                                val size =
                                    cursor2.getLong(gs)

                                println("CC2 File Name: $displayName")
                                println("CC2 File Size: $size bytes")
                            }
                            else{
                                println("column for disp name or size not existing")
                            }
                        }
outputs
I/System.out: CC2 File Name: ExFile1.ext
I/System.out: CC2 File Size: 4831104 bytes
I/System.out: CC2 File Name: ExFile2.ext
I/System.out: CC2 File Size: 337546 bytes
I/System.out: CC2 File Name: ExFile3.ext
I/System.out: CC2 File Size: 7360319 bytes
...
```

So why aren't these other files deleted when I just specify the contenturi path in resolver.delete ?

Comment: Not deleted? Your insert()ed entries are not even listed.

Comment: You are trying to delete a collection. Not a single file. Looks like a bug.

Comment: I wonder why it is named getContentUriForFile() where it is getCollectionUriForFile().

Comment: The insert() into the collection returns a content uri for that file.